# Iterative Factorial Implementation

Tags: algorithm

I found multiple iterative solutions in the net for defining the *factorial* of `n`. They look something like this:

```
int Factorial(int number)
{
   int factorial = 1;

   for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
      factorial *= i;

   return factorial;
}
```

Doesn't `Factorial(0) = 1` and `Factorial(1) = 1`? Therefore, the counter variable inside the for loop should start with **2** since everything below it will yield **1**.

```
   for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++)
      factorial *= i;
```

Is there some reason why they used **1** as the starting number for the counter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter - either 1 or 2 will work, as multiplying by 1 does nothing. However, most loops start with 0 or 1, and this just follows the pattern. Also, the definition of factorial is often stated as the product of all positive integers up to n, so this includes one. Essentially, 1 is, aesthetically, a better starting point.

Answer (score -1):

For iterative functions in python:

```
def iterative_factorial(n):
    x = 1
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        x *= i
    return x
print(iterative_factorial(n))
```

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: (Sure about _not_ using/advertising `xrange`?)