# Having difficulty in computing factorial(n) mod m, when n gets large

Tags: c++, arrays, factorial

I am trying to compute factorial of large numbers mod a large prime number.

`arr[]` stores the value of the factorials for various numbers

If I calculate `fact(32570)` first and then print `arr[1]` and `arr[2]`, then that works.

If I calculate `fact(32571)` first and then print `arr[1]` and `arr[2]`, then that does not work.

However, calculating only `fact(32571)` works.

I really cannot debug this code.

Also,
calculating `fact(32572)` independently does not work.
But, if I calculate `fact(32572)` after finding `fact(32571)` then that works okay.

Whats going on here?

```
#define LL unsigned long long
#define ull unsigned long long

const LL mod=1000000009;

LL arr[1048580];

inline ull mulMod(ull a,ull b,ull c)
{
    if(a<=1000000000ULL && b<=1000000000ULL)
    {
        //cout<<((a%c)*(b%c))%c<<endl;
        ull ret = ((a%c)*(b%c))%c;         //also giving segmentation fault
        return ret;
    }
    ull ret = 0ULL; a=a%c;

    while(b > 0ULL)
    {
        if(b&1ULL) ret = ((ret%c)+(a%c))%c;
        a = (a<<1ULL)%c;
        b>>=1ULL;
    }
    return ret%c;
}

LL fact(LL num)
{
    if(arr[num]==0)
    {
        arr[num]=mulMod(num,fact(num-1),mod);    //gives segmentation fault
        return arr[num];
    }

    return arr[num];
}


int main()
{
    arr[0]=1;
    // does not work
    //    cout<<fact(32571)<<endl;
    //    cout<<arr[1]<<" "<<arr[2]<<endl;

    //works
    //    cout<<fact(325)<<endl;
    //    cout<<arr[1]<<" "<<arr[2]<<endl;

    //also works
    cout<<fact(32571)<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're running out of stack. Every (recursive) call to `fact()` pushes a few values onto the program's stack (return address, saved registers mandated by ABI, etc.). The size of the stack is fixed (depending on your OS, you can change it more or less easily; see `ulimit` if you're using a Bourne-like shell), so eventually, when you have deep recursion like this, there is a “straw that breaks the camel's back”, and when you call one more time, there's no stack left and your program exits with an error message of some kind (e.g. “Segmentation violation” on *Unix*-like OSs).

As Tristan correctly comments below, an [iterative factorial algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514487/iterative-factorial-implementation) does not have this problem.

Comment: As a corollary -- this is a good example why it is usually better to compute factorials using interative algorithms rather than recursive algorithms.

Comment: Tristan: Yes, indeed, or using Stirling's approximation if you don't need exact values. I remember asking myself why he was doing it recursively when I read the question, but decided that this was probably a homework problem or exercise, and then completely forgot about it about half a sentence in to my answer (which I've updated to reflect your comment).

Answer (score 0):

Is 32571 the first integer for which it occurs?

Have you tried out what happens when you change `if(a<=1000000000ULL && b<=1000000000ULL)` to `if(a<mod && b<mod)`?

Answer (score 0):

This solution has space complexity of `O(n)`, but if you don't want to store then you can use the recursive method. You may also keep the modulo(`%`) operator after each calculation:

```
let fac = new Array(n + 1);
fac[0] = 1;
for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    fac[i] = ((fac[i - 1] * i) % m);
}
```